# CSS horizontal scrolling not showing initial values

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a sticky navbar which has circlular avatars, each with an alphabet A-Z, a total of 26 circles. When it is on full screen, it works fine. But when I switch to smaller screen view, the scroll doesnt let me traverse initial values.

[image: works on full screen]

[image: does not scroll past 'J' on the left , cant see values A-I]

As visible, the scroll doesnt scroll past 'J' to the left and thus I can't see values A-I

Here is the code.

```js
let box = document.getElementById('box')
    let circles = ""

    for(let i=65;i<91;i++)
        circles+=`<a href=#><div class="circle" onclick="print('${String.fromCharCode(i)}')"><span class="inner">${String.fromCharCode(i)}</span></div></a>`
    box.innerHTML = circles

    function print(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }
```

```css
        html{font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;}
        a{text-decoration: none;outline: none;}
        #box{
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow-x: auto;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0;
        }
        .circle{
            min-height: 50px;
            min-width: 50px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            background-color: #f9dbbd;
            margin-left: 20px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .inner{
            color: #450920;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height: 1300px;background-color: red;"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <div style="height: 1300px;background-color: red;"></div>
    <div style="height: 1300px;background-color: green;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please use the embedded code snippet tool, to help explain what this code does and does not yet do. And what you what you want it to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `justify-content: center;` from #box

Comment: works! Can you explain why this works after removing justify-content:center ??

Comment: @LakshayDutta, it centers the children along the line, and makes this as the default/starting position, so in smaller view, that center part is somewhere around letter j or k

Answer (score 1):

I have removed 2 rows in the style of box:

```
#box{
    padding: 20px;
    /* width: 100%; */ this one
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* justify-content: center; */ this one
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `justify-content: center`. Also add an `box-sizing` property so you can fully scroll:

```
html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Its very common to remove the default padding and margin from the browser and adding `box-sizing` overall:

Usually we put this at the top of the CSS:

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```